# Reaction numbering using chemformula

Tags: numbering, chemistry, chemformula

Can anyone please guide me to number the reactions separately from equation numbering, while using `chemformula` package.

Comment: The answer to this equation is at the following link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514910/cross-reference-reaction-using-cleveref-in-chemformula-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros} % uses chemformula as default
\usechemmodule{reactions}
%\chemsetup[reactions]{before-tag = R} % if you want it

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    a=b
    \end{equation}

    \begin{reactions}
        A -> B \\
        C ->D
    \end{reactions}

    \begin{align}
    c=d \\
    e = f
    \end{align}

    \begin{reaction}
        E -> F
    \end{reaction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you might to explain which connection there is between `chemmacros` form your answer and `chemformula` from the OP, namely that the formar loads the latter (unless changed by the user) and uses it to format the reactions?

Comment: I'm sorry, I found it obvious.

Comment: Sorry, but I want numbering specifically with `chemformula` package as it is the easiest way for me to write reactions in my manuscript.